# How to show some random variables are multivariate normal?

Tags: statistics

I've got several series of random data, which can be denoted as x1,x2,...,xn.
How do I show that they are subjected to multivariate normal distribution?
I refered to statistics textbooks but only got definations and properties. Do I have to estimate their density functions? Or is there any other necessary conditions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking two different questions:

> How do I show the data originates from a normal distribution?

This is as always a nontrivial question. Usually we compare two hypothesis and can show which one is more *likely*, and that is when you need to provide some furthe assumptions on the distributions you'd want to consider.

But again [Wikipedia has some answers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Multivariate_normality_tests)

> How do I estimate the parameters of a normal distribution.

It depends on what method you are using (you can google those easily). If you're going to go with a maximum likelihood estimation the formula are given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) (in this case ML estimators are just mean/covariance matrix)

Comment: Thank you @flawr. That's very detailed. In my case, each x1~xn seems to be normal distribution viewed from graphs, I'm considering to integrate them. So I guess it's about the first question you mentioned.